# Is term by term integration possible in the following case?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose we are given that $$\int_1^4 g(t)f(t) dt=0 \tag{1}$$

Suppose I am able to write $g(t)$ as Taylor series $\displaystyle g(t)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n t^n$. Now plug in series of $g(t)$ in equation $(1)$. What should be the conditions on $f(t)$ for term by term integration?

I think it should be that $t^n f(t)$ should converge uniformly to $g(t)f(t)$ and that $t^n f(t)$ should be integrable for every $n$. Am I correct?

Comment: If the Taylor series of $g$ converges uniformly for $t\in[1,4]$ and $g(t)f(t)$ is integrable.

Comment: If the Taylor series converges uniformly in the given interval to its function $g$, and of course $g(t)f(t)$ is integrable, then you can integrate term by term.

Comment: Thanks! If all the coefficients in series of $g(t)$ are non-zero, can I conclude that equation $(1)$ is true if and only if $\int_1^4 t^n f(t) dt=0$ for every $n$?

Comment: No, you cant! For example take $g(t) = t+t^2$ and $f = 4 \cdot 1_{[0,1/2]} - 1_{[1/2,1]}$. Then $\int_0^1 f(t) g(t) \, d t = 0$, but $\int_0^1 f(t) t \, d t = 1/8$. If $f$ is a.e. non-negative, then you can conlude that $\int_1^4 t^n f(t) \, d t =0$.

Comment: @p4sch That is great! Actually my $f$  is a.e non-negative. How to prove this fact of yours? Any reference

Comment: If $f$ is non-negative and all $a_n >0$, then we don't need integrability at all. Just apply the monotone convergence theorem. Then we get $0 = \int_1^4 f(t) g(t) \ d t = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_n \int_1^4 t^k f(t) \, d t$. Since all terms on the right-hand side are non-zero, they must be already zero!

Comment: The converse is true in general, that is, if $\int_1^4 t^n f(t) dt=0$ for any function (negative or positive) and for every $n$, then equation $(1)$ is zero, right?

Comment: If you assume that $g(t)f(t)$ is integrable and the Taylor series converges uniformly in the given interval, then yes.

Comment: @p4sch Yep, I have these conditions. Thank you for your time.